# Setting passed in values to event listeners in a loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, svg

This feels like a very basic question, but I can't seem to find an answer t it. I have an array of clickable svg rects that have id's "texture-1", "texture-2" etc. The textureInput array holds the getElementById's for those rects, that call a changeTexture() function on click. I want "1" to be passed into the changeTexture() function when "texture-1" is clicked on etc.

Manually assigning these values works: e.g.

```
  textureInput[0].addEventListener('click', function(){changeTexture("0")}, false);
  textureInput[1].addEventListener('click', function(){changeTexture("1")}, false);
```

But doing the same thing in a loop does not:

```
for (var i=0; i<maxTextures; i++){
   textureInput[i].addEventListener('click', function(){changeTexture(i)}
};
```

Is it passing in the then current value of "i" at event time - which is undefined outside the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a closure so that a new copy of the `i` variable is made, otherwise it will use the one that belongs to the `for` loop. Try this:

```
for (var i=0; i<maxTextures; i++){
  textureInput[i].addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
    return function () {
      changeTexture(i);
    };
  })(i));
};
```

Comment: thanks daniel - this code worked. There's nothing in JavaScript that can convert a variable to a static value?

Comment: @MichaelMullany Not that I'm aware of, this is how you have to do it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure. One simple way is wrap an IIFE around the code within the loop

```
for (var i=0; i<maxTextures; i++){
  (function(i){
      textureInput[i].addEventListener('click', function(){changeTexture(i);}
   })(i);
};
```